# Dynamical multiple pages pdf export using jspdf

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf

I'm trying to export single pdf file with multiple pages and the data is feeded dynamically or from the html element using jsPdf. But i dunno whats going wrong the data is not able to render to pdf or if the page exceeds more than one page, then tha pdf is exported as blank pdf with single page.

Here is my code
html

```
    <button mat-button (click)="exportAsPDF()">Export</button>
    <div class="page" *ngFor="let page of pages; index as i" id='pdfExport1' #pdfExport1
    [style.height]="sizePage.height + 'cm'"
    [style.width]="sizePage.width + 'cm'"
    (click)="clickPage(i)">
    <div class="content" 
      [style.paddingTop]="paddingPage.top + 'cm'"
      [style.paddingRight]="paddingPage.right + 'cm'"
      [style.paddingBottom]="paddingPage.bottom + 'cm'"
      [style.paddingLeft]="paddingPage.left + 'cm'"  
      [id]="'content-' + i" contenteditable="true"
      (input)="inputContent($event['data'], i)">
    </div>
  </div>
```

typescript code

```
  exportAsPDFDynamic()
  {
    console.log(this.pages)
    let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'cm', 'a4'); 
    this.pages.forEach((el, index)=>{
      let idTag='content-'+ index
      let data = document.getElementById(idTag); 
      html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
        pdf.addPage('','p')        
        const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')  
        pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, 0, 20, 31.0);  
          
      });
    })

    pdf.save('Filename.pdf');   
  }
```

Please help me to export the number of pages dynamically and export the pdf with multiple pages

Comment: Hi KJ,  here i'm trying to loop the html document id of 'content-1 ', 'content-2',...'content-n' by adding a new page to the pdf file, the pages are adding to the pdf file but i found blank page is displayed. Is that right?

Comment: did you find the answer ? i am also struggling with same issue.